# Constraining instantiated UIView from NIB to other UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm having problems adding constraints to a newly instantiated UIView from a NIB to another UIView, which is part of another NIB.

What I want to do exactly is this:

1. Load a UIView from a NIB file. (Done)
2. Have a UIView component in the first NIB file that acts as a container to another UIView. Gray background. (Done)
3. Load the second UIView (Green background) from another NIB file and place it inside the first UIView (the gray one). (Here lies the problem) What I mean as *inside* is exactly in the place of the container. The container UIView is 300x280 (the gray background), and so is the external UIView (the green background).

I can add the second UIView inside the first UIView, because I can see it, but the constraints are off. The first UIView uses AutoLayout to accommodate itself, but the second not, the components in the second UIView are lay out using IB.

**Observation:**

If I add background color to the second UIView when I add it to the container UIView, the frame fits perfectly, but the components not, they always seem off. I have tried `clipToBounds = true` and it works by keeping the components inside the UIView, but I can't find the way to align all components (UITextFields, UIButtons, etc.) to both UIViews.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code for the container/first UIView:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // loginView  = IS THE UIView in the second NIB.        
    // otherViews = IS THE UIView CONTAINER in the first NIB.

    let loginView = BCAKLoginView() // LOAD NIB FILE
    self.loginView.frame  = self.otherViews.bounds
    self.loginView.hidden = false
    self.loginView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.loginView.clipsToBounds = true

    self.otherViews.addSubview(loginView) // HERE I ADD THE SECOND NIB TO UIView.

    let constraintLeading = NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: self.loginView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.otherViews,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0
    )
    let constraintWidth = NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: self.loginView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.otherViews,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0
    )
    let constraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: self.loginView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.otherViews,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0
    )
    let constraintBottom = NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: self.loginView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.otherViews,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0
    )

    self.otherViews.addConstraint(constraintLeading)
    self.otherViews.addConstraint(constraintWidth)
    self.otherViews.addConstraint(constraintTop)
    self.otherViews.addConstraint(constraintBottom)
}
```

Comment: You need to call `loginView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`

Comment: no. you need to call `loginView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

Comment: @AndreSlotta - Thanks for correction. Silly mistake from my side :).

Comment: I did that already, makes no difference. Both **true & false**.

Comment: for me this looks like the loginview is added to the main view instead of the light gray containerview. is it possible that something is wrong with the IBOutlet for otherviews?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer my own question..

The problem was when I instantiated the second NIB file (UIView). In `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`. I was adding it as a subview to myself, hence adding an extra UIView between `loginView` and `otherViews`. That was it... When I removed this extra view, everything aligned itself.